# jQuery: update content every week (or long period of time)

Tags: jquery

Let me start by saying that I'm not a power-JavaScript/jQuery programmer, I do very basic things with it, yet sometimes things get a little hairy for me, like this one.

**My case**:

I have a list of testimonials (around 20) and every week (Mondays) I need to updated them.

**My problem:**

I update them manually. I mean, I open Dreamweaver, update the jQuery code for the corresponding testimonial number, and upload to server.

**What I need:**

A way to have this be automated... as best as possible.

**HTML of testimonials:**

```
<body>
<div class="quotes-container quote-1">
  <div class="quote">Testimonial...</div>
  <div class="author">Author</div>
</div>
<div class="quotes-container quote-2">
  <div class="quote">Testimonial...</div>
  <div class="author">Author</div>
</div>
<div class="quotes-container quote-3">
  <div class="quote">Testimonial...</div>
  <div class="author">Author</div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

**My jQuery used to change the testimonial:**

`$(function(){
$('#quotes-wrapper').load('/static-files/testimonials.html div.quote-1');
});`

As you can see all I need to do is to manually change *div.quote-1* to *div.quote-2* or *div.quote-3* and so on.

But I know there's got to be a way to have jQuery change these testimonials 'dynamically' every Monday (or Tuesday, or any day I choose for that matter), and not have to keep reminders around to not forget to change the testimonials every Monday.

Any ideas how can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you work with PHP at all and do you have access to a database?  You(with Stack assistance) could create a mini content management system that allows you to just enter them and hit 'Submit' and manage them in a, sort of, user control panel.  Eh?

Comment: d2burke, we actually use .NET. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find out the week of year to select the div:

(got the code from http://javascript.about.com/library/blweekyear.htm)

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
  return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
$(function(){
  var today = new Date();
  var weekno = today.getWeek();
  $('#quotes-wrapper').load('/static-files/testimonials.html div.quote-'+weekno);
});
```

Comment: elektronikLexikon, I tried it but it didn't work, it hides the entire "#quotes-wrapper" container.

I added a ' to the end of "+weekno" and it now shows the "#quotes-wrapper" container though, but no testimonial:

".load('/static-files/testimonials.html div.quote-'+weekno');"

Comment: weekno is 38 in this week. Is there a "div.quote-38"?

Comment: Oh wow! It worked! :D

This is pretty much what I needed, all I need to do now is just change my div.quote-1, div.quote-2, div.quote-3, etc, to the proper number of the week we are at right now.

I only have a total of 21 testimonials, so I was numbering them 1 through 21 of course. Now all I need to do is change the numbers to the corresponding week.

Thanks a lot elektronikLexikon!

Comment: In the getWeek function, we should rather return Math.floor or you'll miss the first week of the year.