# jQuery: week of year script acting up

Tags: jquery, week-number

A while ago I needed a script to update some content every week, and my question was answered in [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701276/jquery-update-content-every-week-or-long-period-of-time).

--

Now, and I'm not a jQuery pro like you :), but the "problem" I have is that today (the moment of this post) it's week #52 but the script wasn't working, it wasn't showing the content for week #52, so I changed my HTML to week #53, and it worked.

The "problem" is that there's no week #53, so I'm afraid I'm going to have to change my HTML to continue counting for week #54, #56, #57 and so on, when those weeks don't exist.

**Here's an extract of the HTML (*the structure repeats over the weeks, content changes of course*):**

```
<div class="quotes-container quote-53">
 <div class="quote">Quote here...</div>
 <div class="author">&mdash; Author </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}

jQuery(function(){  
 var today = new Date();
 var weekno = today.getWeek();
 jQuery('#quotes-wrapper').load('/common/testimonials.html div.quote-'+weekno);
});
</script>
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks a lot for any help on this.

Comment: Do you want the week based on how many "Sundays" there've been? Or do you want it based on how many 7 day periods since the first day of the year?

Comment: A year is 1-2 days longer than 52 weeks.  So, yes, you're going to have 53 weeks showing up, unless your code is smart enough to consider the very end of the year as part of week 1 of the following year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** The script you're using considers a "week" to be Sunday - Saturday. Since a year doesn't always start on a Sunday, it considers the first partial week to be week 1.

If you simply want 7 say periods since the first of the year, use the script below. If you want it based on Sunday, then the script you're using would be correct.

---

There is a week `#53`. It's just not a full week.

But we are in week `52`. <s>I'm guessing the current script doesn't account for leap years.</s>

Instead you can calculate the day of this year, and divide that by 7.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/etTS2/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
      var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
      var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
      var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan +1)/86400000);
      return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
    };


    jQuery(function(){  
     var today = new Date();
     var weekno = today.getWeek();
     jQuery('#quotes-wrapper').load('/common/testimonials.html div.quote-'+weekno);
    });

</script>
```

You'll still get a result of `53` on the last day of the year (or last two days in a leap year).

**EDIT:** Fixed a offset of `1` on the `dayOfYear`.

Comment: Won't there still be issues at the beginning of next year?  After the first of January you'll be back to week 1.  Y2K all over again man! Seriously, though, I suggest just harding 2010 into the onejan variable.  i.e. var onejan = new Date(2010,0,1);

Comment: And the code from the example has jan 1st split the week in two?  I think that's unnecessary for what you are doing. But patrick's code fixes that.

Comment: patrick, thanks for your answer. I tried the code but it didn't work, it's not showing my testimonials/quotes. Do I have to change something in my jQuery function as well? Sorry, I'm new to this. Thanks again. Just FYI, the idea is to keep using this script next year as well, and so on.

Comment: @ptpaterson: I think OP wants to be back to week one after the first of the year. My code was off by one day, but I fixed that. I see now that the reason the original code was splitting the first week was that it was intended to be a calculation of how many weeks *starting on Sunday* there've been, counting the first partial week as 1.

Comment: @Ricardo: You would replace the first half of your example code (above the line break in the middle). The second half should stay the same. I'll update my answer to include your example code. Also, I made a small fix.

Comment: ...also, you should note that my code changes the quote on whatever day was the first of the year. So if the first of the year was a Wednesday, then the quote will change on that day. If you want to change it every Sunday, then use the original code you had, but just add one more quote for week `53`. It will start over after the first of the year.

Comment: Awesome patrick, it worked perfect and your explanations are great. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it :)