# Week picker in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I found in demos section about the Data picker. But do we have a picker that will act as a week picker letting us just select a week.

**UPDATE:**
I want the calendar view to be be looking this way but with the theming of JQuery Mobile: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan has provided a solution for this:

In his words:

I've added a demo of this working on the main demo page, it is
the last one under 'Advanced Demos' :
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work with jQM but I did see this link: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

These also might be related:

- [jQuery: week of year script acting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539775/jquery-week-of-year-script-acting-up)
- http://jsfiddle.net/etTS2/2/
- http://jquery142.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-get-week-number-for-date-in.html

Comment: @krishnan jQm does have a Datepicker http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/ I know there are some issues with this but you could try to add the theme as they have done to the HTML here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-themes.html

Comment: Are you asking me to add theme to UI-date picker of JQM. My problem is not with the way the picker in the link I referred looks, but in the functionality. Do you think there is any similar one available in JQM or an easy way to customize the one I have referred to look like a JQM control?

Comment: The only other date picker I found I like is DateBox: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ I know the developer is very friendly and takes feature requests that often come out in his next release.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I too saw that. I will suggest him to take this feature too.